# Add class to submenu item by data id when the parent has active class jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to add class for the child menu when it's parent has active class. Child may has several parents.

I wrote this code but it's don't work.

```js
   

 if ($('.megamenu__list li[data-id]').hasClass('menu__list--active')) {
       var $aSelect = $(this);
       $('.megamenu__subcategory li').addClass('menu__subcategory--inactive').removeClass('menu__subcategory--child')
       .filter(function() {
        return $(this).data('id').includes($aSelect.data('id'));
       })  
       .addClass('menu__subcategory--child').removeClass('menu__subcategory--inactive');  
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="megamenu__list">        
   <li data-id="1" class=""><a href="#">Menu 1</span></a></li>

   <li data-id="2" class=""><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>

   <li data-id="3" class=""><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>

   <li data-id="4" class=""><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>

   <li data-id="5" class="menu__list--active"><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
 </ul>
 
<div class="megamenu__subcategory">
   <ul>
      <li data-id="[1,3]" class="menu__subcategory--inactive"><a href="#">SubMenu 1</a></li>
      <li data-id="[2]" class="menu__subcategory--inactive"><a href="#">SubMenu 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
      <li data-id="[3]" class="menu__subcategory--inactive"><a href="#">SubMenu 3</a></li>
      <li data-id="[4]" class="menu__subcategory--inactive"><a href="#">SubMenu 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the css as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EXPLAIN YOUR CODE:**

This code is in click function ?

```
// if(hasclass), it's not function so this in this condition is undefined
if($('.megamenu__list li[data-id]').hasClass('menu__list--active'))
{
    // Get this, but this == function/object parent
    var $aSelect = $(this);

    // Get all .megamenu__subcategory li
    $('.megamenu__subcategory li')

        // Update class
        .addClass('menu__subcategory--inactive')
        .removeClass('menu__subcategory--child')

        // Select all elems with data-id attriute include parent data id
        .filter(function()
        {
            return $(this).data('id').includes($aSelect.data('id'));
        })

        // Update class in this select
        .addClass('menu__subcategory--child')
        .removeClass('menu__subcategory--inactive')
    ;
}
```

**MY SOLUTION:**

```
// When click menu
$('.megamenu__list li').click(function()
{
    // Remove all active menu
    $('.megamenu__list li').removeClass('menu__list--active');

    // Add class active for this menu
    $(this).addClass('menu__list--active');

    // Get menu id (parseint beacause jsonparse used)
    var menuId = parseInt($(this).data('id'));

    // Force reset all class category
    $('.megamenu__subcategory li').attr('class','menu__subcategory--inactive');

    // Update all categories with id
    $('.megamenu__subcategory li').each(function()
    {
        // If data id contain menuid (why jsonparse ? If my menuId == 1, match with data-id="[11,12,13]")
        if(JSON.parse($(this).data('id')).indexOf(menuId) !== -1) $(this).addClass('menu__subcategory--child').removeClass('menu__subcategory--inactive');
    });
});
```

**[EDIT] WITHOUT CLICK:**

**jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/8f3zyLgx/**

Comment: no, this code check active class after load the page

Comment: The javascript avoids reloading the page, too bad. I edit my post.

Comment: it is does not work.   The class .menu__list--active is added only for  one of the menu items, for example if we load the Page 1,  we have .menu__list--active in Menu 1,  if we load Page 2, we have .menu__list--active in  Menu 2. Then i need to highlight the child menu, and it's the separate list in html. But code founds child menu by data id and must   highlight them if there's parent item has .menu__list--active

Comment: Sorry, `json.parse` has already set by jquery, try jsfiddle (in edited post).